# use a select sum query to find the max and min of the sum

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to answer this question in mysql..."What product sells the most/least?" I want to add the max and min function to my selet statement but not sure how or where.

This is what I am currently trying to add the max and min statements to

```
SELECT prod_nbr,sum(sls_qty) AS sls_qty
FROM total_sales
GROUP BY prod_nbr
ORDER BY sls_qty DESC;
```

Comment: You don't need `max` or `min` there. That query tells you which sells the most all by itself. Change `desc` to `asc` to get the one that sells the least.

Comment: i understand that. but i just want the query to show 2 rows - the min and the max products by sales quantity.

Comment: So do two queries and combine them with `UNION` to get two rows.

Comment: how would i write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, here is an option using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    prod_nbr,
    sls_qty,
    IF(rn_min = 1, 'min', 'max') type
FROM
(
    SELECT prod_nbr, SUM(sls_qty) AS sls_qty,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sls_qty)) rn_min,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sls_qty) DESC) rn_max
    FROM total_sales
    GROUP BY prod_nbr
) t
WHERE 1 IN (rn_min, rn_max)
ORDER BY sls_qty;
```

Comment: how could this be adjusted so that this include the top 3 max and bottom 3 min?

Comment: Use the following `WHERE` clause: `WHERE 3 IN (rn_min, rn_max)`

Answer (score 0):

Do a union of two queries.

```
SELECT 'max' AS TYPE,
       prod_nbr,
       sum(sls_qty) AS sls_qty
FROM total_sales
GROUP BY prod_nbr
ORDER BY sls_qty DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT 'min' AS TYPE,
       prod_nbr,
       sum(sls_qty) AS sls_qty
FROM total_sales
GROUP BY prod_nbr
ORDER BY sls_qty ASC
```